# SSL on Google Compute Engine with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

#### Summary:

I'm trying to set-up a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) server on Google's Compute Engine (*GCE*) to work with HTTPS, but the remote server doesn't seem to respond when accessed through `https://...`.

#### What I tried so far:

I've acquired a certificate from Comodo, put it on the backend, included it in the code, and created an HTTPS server as follows:

```
var app = express();
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),
};

...
        https.createServer(options,app).listen('443',function(){
                console.log('https ready')
        });
```

I've also added the following firewall rule:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-https --description "https server" --allow tcp:443
--format json
```

When I run the server on my local machine and try accessing it using `https://localhost:443` through Chrome, I get the expected:

> This server could not prove that it is localhost; its security certificate is from www.domain_name.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Meaning the server is properly configured to be able to recognize the `https` request, but since the certificate does not belong to localhost, it results in a warning.

#### The problem:

When I run the same code on my GCE instance, which runs on the domain name associated with the certificate, I get no response from the server. Moreover, according to [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/) there *is* incoming `https` traffic on the correct port:

[image: tcpdump output for my case]

I ran `netstat -ltnp` with the following results:

- When I run the server with `https` configuration shown above, there is no record for the 443 port.
- When I run the server with `http` configuration on port 8080 there is a record for that port and everything is working fine.
- When I run the server with `http` **AND** `https` configurations (listening to port 8080 and port 443), there is no records for either and there is no response from the server at all...

**My question is**: How can I get my GCE instance to respond to `https` requests? What else should I do or test?

I found several questions on this topic ([q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069050/does-google-compute-engine-support-https) ,[q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271759/how-do-i-configure-google-compute-engine-to-use-https-for-nodejs-server), [q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656912/https-not-working-on-google-compute-engine), [q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160247/google-compute-engine-adding-disk-and-ssl-support)), and it seems I did everything that was recommended there, yet my problem still remains.

Comment: Did you check (using something like tcpdump) that the HTTPS traffic gets to your instance?

Comment: @AndreasVeithen Yes there is traffic coming in, see my edit

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -ltnp | grep 443`?

Comment: @AndreasVeithen I've made another edit. The 433 port is not listed by the `netstat -ltnp` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are running the server as a non root user and it fails to bind to port 443 (which is a privileged port).

Comment: I have same issue but still happens with me